# How can I input an if statement inside a while loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ex11 
{
static Scanner type=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int fact=1;
        System.out.println("Enter a natural number ");
        int num=type.nextInt();

        int i=1;
        while(i<=num)
        {
            fact*=i;
            i++;    
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of number " + num + " is " + fact);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to place a conditional statement inside the while loop. The condition is to test for would be that of, if num is a negative number, `S.O.P.("You entered a negative #");` in other words,

```
if(num<0)
    S.O.P.("You entered a negative #");
```

However it doesn't print it properly.

Comment: did you try actually putting an if-statement in the while loop?

Comment: First, You have set i = 1 & then you have set the condition in while loop as i<= num. When you will enter a negative number this will not enter the while loop & hence will not execute what is within while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check inside the loop then it will not work it will still multiply the `fact`. You need to make sure that the `num` is not negative before you start the while loop.

```
int num = 0;
do {
    if (num<0){
        System.out.println("You printed out a negative number");
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a natural number ");
    int num=type.nextInt();
} while (num<0);
```

Also on a side note you should probably close your scanners when you are done using them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question .... like this:

```
int i = 1;     // HERE
while (i <= num) {
    if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("You entered a negative #");
    }
    fact *= i;
    i++;    
}
```

However that is not going to work.

Suppose that "num" that you read is less than zero.

- At the statement labeled "HERE", we set "i" to one.
- In the next statement, we test "i < num".
- Since "num" is less than zero, that test gives "false" and we skip over the entire loop!

That means that your conditional statement in the loop body would not be executed ... if "num" is less than zero.

Since this is obviously homework, I will leave it to you to figure out what you *should* be doing here.  But (HINT!) it is not putting the conditional inside the loop.

(Please note: I have corrected a number of style errors in your code.  Compare your original version with mine.  This is how you *should* write Java code.)

Comment: @Ryan - Ever heard of the Southern Hemisphere?  Ever heard of Summer Schools?   Moocs?   Besides, whether it is strictly homework or not is beside the point.  It is a LEARNING exercise and the OP will learn a lot more by solving the problem for himself.

Answer (score 0):

The question is hard to understand but from what i read it appears you want a loop to run until a value is entered that meets your pre-condition of being positive

```
System.out.println("Enter a non negative number :: ");
int num = type.nextInt();
while(num < 0){
    System.out.println("The number you entered was negative!");
    System.out.println("Enter a non negative number :: ");
    num = type.nextInt();
}
```

Loops like this are crucial to making sure the data that you are using is within the pre-condition of your operation which could cause `DivideByZero` errors or other problems. This loop should be placed before you ever use the value of `num` so you can make sure it is within context of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the `num` is negative, it won't go inside the `while loop` that is because before the `while loop` you have initialize `i=1`, since any negative number is lesser than `1` the condition for `while loop` become false. If you want to check whether `num` is negative insert the `if condition` before the `while loop` as follows

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ex11 
    {
    static Scanner type=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int fact=1;
        System.out.println("Enter a natural number ");
        int num=type.nextInt();

        int i=1;

         if(num < 0) {
           System.out.println("You entered a negative #");
          }
         else{

              while(i<=num)
              {
               fact*=i;
               i++;    
               }
        System.out.println("Factorial of number " + num + " is " + fact);
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to check whether the number is less than 0. This is to be done while taking the input. You can just take the input inside a while loop in this manner:

```
System.out.println("Enter a natural #");
while(true){ //loop runs until broken
    num = type.nextInt();
    if(num>=0)
        break;
    System.out.println("Wrong input. Please enter a positive number");
}
```

The program control breaks out of the loop if `num>=0`, i.e., positive, else, it continues to the next part of the loop and displays the error message and takes the input again.

Please note that natural numbers are the ones >= 1. In your program, you are actually trying to input a whole number which is >= 0.